# jUnit: How to filter tests found in multiple suites

Tags: java, junit, junit4

When jUnit runs a test suite containing multiple "sub suites", is it possible to filter tests found in different suites as to make them run only **once**? I'm working on a project with many database integration tests so it's desirable run these only once as to make it quicker.

Consider this "main suite":

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses
({
    ModuleASuite.class,
    ModuleBSuite.class,
    // More suites...
})
public class MainSuite
{}
```

And these "sub suites":

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses
({
    TestA1.class,
    TestA2.class,
    //... More tests only related to ModuleA

    SomeTestUsedByManyModules.class
})
public class ModuleASuite
{}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses
({
    TestB1.class,
    TestB2.class,
    //... More tests only related to ModuleB

    SomeTestUsedByManyModules.class
})
public class ModuleBSuite
{}
```

Currently when running `MainSuite` using jUnit 4.4 (using Eclipse or Ant) it runs `SomeTestUsedByManyModules` twice. How can I make it run only once? I thought of making my own [Runner](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) but maybe there's an easer solution for this?

Comment: I have never heard of JUnit keeping track of whether it's run a test method before -- after all, maybe that's what you intended?   Writing your own runner is probably the only way.  (Well, you could add code to each test method to register itself to some shared hash so it can decide whether to run or not.  Pretty ugly.)   Writing test runners admittedly looks daunting, but it looks much harder than it is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with @RunWith(Suite), but what about a different approach?  [ClassPathSuite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) lets you provide test name patterns to avoid the need to list them all out manually.